# Groupby in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My code is working, which is good lol, but the output needs to be different in how it is viewed.

**UPDATED CODE SINCE RECIEVING ANSWER**

```
import pandas as pd

# Import File
YMM = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/PCTR261010/Desktop/OMIX_YMM_2016.xlsx').groupby(['Make','Model']).agg({'StartYear':'min', 'EndYear':'max'})

print(YMM)
```

The output looks like **Make | Model | StartYear | EndYear**, with all the makes listed down column the Make Column next to the Model Column. But the Makes are filtered like a Pivot table.

Here is a screen shot:
[image]

I need American Motors next to every American Motors Model, every Buick next to every Buick Model and so on.

Here is the link to sample data:
http://jmp.sh/KLZKWVZ

Comment: Don't link to data. Share it here instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
res = YMM.groupby(['Make','Model'], as_index=False).agg({'StartYear':'min', 'EndYear':'max'})
```

or

```
res = YMM.groupby(['Make','Model']).agg({'StartYear':'min', 'EndYear':'max'}).reset_index()
```

Comment: That's it! I played with .agg and couldn't get to that. Now I just need the Make to repeat down the column next to the Model.

Comment: @SamRussoPalmer, glad it helps. My corporate firewall doesn't allow me to download your sample data... I can download it later from home. Could you post an example of desired data set, because (`need the Make to repeat down the column next to the Model.`) not clear to me

Comment: Updated, but I had to do a screen shot, but under it I explained.

Comment: try `reset_index()` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

With your own code

```
Min = YMM.groupby(['Make','Model']).StartYear.min()
Max = YMM.groupby(['Make','Model']).EndYear.max()

Min['Endyear']=Max.EndYear
```